Gram Schmidt Process Variation: How to prove mutual orthogonality of $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$?
$w_1 = u_1/\|u_1\|$,
$w_2 = v_2/\|v_2\|$ where $v_2 = u_2 −(u_2·w_1)w_1$,
and $w_3 = v_3/\|v_3\|$ where $v_3 = u_3 −(u_3·w_1)w_1 −(u_3·w_2)w_2$
This is a variation of the Gram Schmidt Process. Using dot products to prove the mutual orthogonality seems to be the key, though I am not sure how to carry this out in the fine details to show that $w_1·w_2 = 0,\, w_1·w_3 = 0,\, w_2·w_3 = 0$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would like to note that I was able to show w1 and w2 orthogonality, it is the pairs involving w3 that I am at a loss on.

$$ \begin{align}\|u_1\| \|v_2\| \times \langle w_1,w_2 \rangle 
&=  \langle u_1,\left(u_2 −  \langle u_2,w_1\rangle w_1\right)\rangle \\
&= \langle u_1, u_2\rangle - \langle u_2,w_1\rangle \langle u_1,w_1\rangle \\ &=  \langle u_1, u_2\rangle - \frac{1}{\|u_1\|^2} \langle u_2,u_1\rangle \langle u_1,u_1\rangle \\ 
&= 0
\end{align}$$
By induction, we can show the orthogonality for the other pairs.

Thank you so much, this I was able to accomplish. It was the other pairs, specifically those involving w3 that gave me trouble. I appreciate all of your help.

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you seem to have answered it yourself. As the dot product between any two orthogonal vectors is equal to zero, you can simply compute dot products of the resulting vectors. For vectors $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$:
If $w_1 \cdot w_2 = 0$, $w_2 \cdot w_3 = 0$, and $w_1 \cdot w_3 = 0$, then they are mutually orthogonal. Showing that the dot products equal zero proves orthogonality. To compute the dot product of two vectors, you multiply them element-wise and add the result. For example, if $w_1 = (a,b,c)$ and $w_2= (x,y,z)$, then $w_1 \cdot w_2 = a\cdot x + b\cdot y + c\cdot z$..
It is a simple and efficient method of ensuring that you performed the Gram-Schmidt process correctly.
Here are a couple of great sources for proofs and more information related to Gram-Schmidt and Orthogonality.
Interactive Linear Algebra Textbook
Proof Wiki
Brilliant Math Wiki

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
